# Differentiation Using Limits

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f(x)$ is differentiable at the point $x=c$ then $$f'(c)=\lim_{h, k \to 0^{+}}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c-k)}{k+h}$$
$$$$Now as $$\frac{f(c+h)-f(c-k)}{k+h}=\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{k+h}+\frac{f(c)-f(c-k)}{k+h}=\frac{h}{k+h}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}+\frac{k}{k+h}\frac{f(c)-f(c-k)}{k}$$. Also as $k, h \to 0^{+}$ both $k$ and $h$ are positive and hence $\frac{h}{k+h}$ and $\frac{k}{k+h}$ are both less than $1$ and hence their limits as $k, h \to 0^{+}$ is also less than $1$ but as $$\frac{h}{k+h}+\frac{k}{k+h}=1$$ and hence the sum of their limits is also 1$$$$(As If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions with limits $a$ and $b$ respectively such that $f(x)+g(x)=1$ then $$1=\lim f(x)+g(x)=\lim f(x)+\lim g(x)=a+b$$. Let the limit of $\frac{h}{k+h}$ and $\frac{k}{k+h}$ be $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively. Then as $k, h \to 0^{+}$ $$\frac{h}{k+h}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}+\frac{k}{k+h}\frac{f(c)-f(c-k)}{k}$$ remains close to $L_1f'(c)+L_2f'(c)=(L_1+L_2)f'(c)=f'(c)$ and hence the required thing is proved.
$$$$ Is The Proof Correct, PLZ Help.

Comment: $h/(h+k)$ doesn't have a limit when $h,k \to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good, but as I commented it's not right. Instead, since $f$ is differentiable at $c$ there exists a function $\varepsilon$ such that for $x$ small enough, $f(c+x)=f(c)+xf'(c)+x\varepsilon(x)$ and $\varepsilon(x)\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0$. Therefore, for $h,k>0$ small enough,

$$\frac{f(c+h)-f(c-k)}{k+h}=\frac{(h+k)f'(c)+h\varepsilon(h)+k\varepsilon(-k)}{k+h}=f'(c)+\frac{h\varepsilon(h)}{k+h}+\frac{k\varepsilon(-k)}{k+h}$$

Yet,

$$\left|\frac{h\varepsilon(h)}{k+h}+\frac{k\varepsilon(-k)}{k+h}\right|\leq\frac{h|\varepsilon(h)|}{k+h}+\frac{k|\varepsilon(-k)|}{k+h}\leq|\varepsilon(h)|+|\varepsilon(-k)|\xrightarrow[h,k\to0^+]{}0$$

Hence the desired result.